# How do I fix the configuration for monitors?

Tags: nvidia, 14.04, configuration

I'm new to Ubuntu and I've been using it for about 2 weeks now and I have the following problem: I installed the NVidia driver version 331.38. Then I restarted the computer and after I logged-in a dialog popped up with the following error message:

```
Could not apply the stored configuration for monitors
- Error on line 1 char 1 : Document must begin will an element (e.g <book>)
```

Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Is your Video Card Driver installed correct?

Try to install it with the following package `xserver-xorg-video-all`.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic xserver-xorg-video-all libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core
```